# Magento 1.9 Navigation link to home page

Tags: magento

How would I make a link from the main navigation to the home page (or any other page)?

I can do it in the Admin using

```
Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management -> Add URL Rewrite
```

Then creating a `Custom Rewrite`.

I use the hardcoded link to the homepage `http:\\somedomain\magento` as the `Target Path` and set it to `Permanent 301` Redirect.

Then I delete the original `System` rewrite for the home category.

This works until it's reindexed, then the original `System` rewrite for that category comes back and the `Custom` one I created doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was doing wrong.  I shouldn't have deleted the original system rewrite.  These are the steps to make custom links from the navigation menu.

1) Copy the `Target Path` from the `System` Category rewrite

2) Change the redirect to `Permanent 301` for the `System` Category rewrite

3) Create a new `Custom` rewrite.

4) In the new `Custom` rewrite, paste the copy from #1 into `Request Path`

5) For `ID Path` put the `URL Key` for the page to be linked, for default page is  `/`

6) For `Target Path` put the path to the new page (e.g `/` or `/contacts`)

This article explains it in detail : http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar/